# column combination from separare data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, multiple-columns, reshape

I have multiple text files that I have imported using

```
colnames<-c("cellID", "X", "Y", "Area", "AVGFP", "DeviationGFP", "AvgRFP", "DeviationsRFP", "Slice", "GUI-ID")
stats <- apply(data.frame(list.files()), 1, read.table,sep="", header=F, col.names=colnames)
names(stats) <- paste0("slice",seq_along(1:40))
```

This is what slice1 from stats looks like :

```
   cellID         X          Y Area    AVGFP DeviationGFP   AvgRFP DeviationsRFP Slice GUI.ID
1       1  18.20775  26.309859  568 5.389085     7.803248 12.13028      5.569880     0      1
2       2  39.78755   9.505495  546 5.260073     6.638375 17.44505     17.220153     0      1
3       3  30.50000  28.250000    4 6.000000     4.000000  8.50000      1.914854     0      1
4       4  38.20233 132.338521  257 3.206226     5.124264 14.04669      4.318130     0      1
5       5  43.22467  35.092511  454 6.744493     9.028574 11.49119      5.186897     0      1
6       6  57.06534 130.355114  352 3.781250     5.713022 20.96591     14.303546     0      1
7       7  86.81765  15.123529 1020 6.043137     8.022179 16.36471     19.194279     0      1
8       8  75.81932 132.146417  321 3.666667     5.852172 99.47040     55.234726     0      1
9       9 110.54277  36.339233  678 4.159292     6.689660 12.65782      4.264624     0      1
10     10 127.83480  11.384886  569 4.637961     6.992881 11.39192      4.287963     0      1
```

All of the other data sets look the same except they all have varying row length (some go up to 2000 cells)

I want to take 1 column from each data.frame (slice1....slice40) and put it into a new data.frame. I want the new data.frame to have the column name and I want the column names in the new data.frame to be called slice1...slice40.

To summarize with specifics:

From each slice1-40, I want to take all of the values from AVGFP and put them in a new data.frame
The new data.frame should be called "AVGFP"
There should be 40 columns with headers "slice1, slice2, ... , slice40"
There should be "NA" in each empty cell that arises from one slice being shorter than another.

I really appreciate any and all help. I have been fumbling around with `apply`, `plyr`, `split`, `reshape`, `melt`, `merge`, and `aggregate` with no luck.

Comment: Are the values in AVGFP to be matched according to `callID`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match by `cellID` then try this:

```
L <- lapply(stats, `[`, c("cellID","AVGFP"))

AVGFP <- Reduce(function(x,y)
         merge(x,y,by="cellID",all=TRUE,suffixes=c(ncol(x),ncol(x)+1)), L)

names(AVGFP)[-1] <- paste0("slice", 1:40)
```

---

If you want to simply paste the columns together, try this:

First get the max length of the dataframes:

```
maxL <- max(sapply(stats, nrow))
```

Now create a list where each column is extended with `NA`s to the maximum length:

```
L <- lapply(stats, function(x) c(x$AVGFP, rep(NA, maxL-nrow(x))))
```

Put the columns together in a matrix:

```
M <- do.call(cbind, L)
```

Coerce to dataframe:

```
AVGFP <- as.data.frame(M)
```

Add the names you want:

```
names(AVGFP) <- paste0("slice", 1:40)
```

Comment: after a preliminary look at your bottom suggestion the data looks great! There are 40 columns labelled slice1 - slice40 with the GFP data and NA where there is no data. When I tried your "AVGFP <- Reduce(function(x,y)merge(x,y,by="cellID",all=TRUE), L)" suggestion I received this error :Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names

Comment: @user2813055 fixed, it is a problem with `merge` because it adds default suffixes ".x" and ".y" to conflicting column names, but doesn't check if the new names do no conflict with other columns. The hack `suffixes=c(ncol(x),ncol(x)+1)` fixes this problem, since `x` is growing columnwise at each reducing step.

Comment: thanks for following up. I am having a hard time understanding the commands to make this work. Would you mind walking through the second set of commands that initially worked. I believe this will give me a better understanding moving forward.

Comment: @user2813055 what commands specifically you don't understand?

Comment: I see that maxL is searching for the maximum number of rows in stats.I am not sure how function(x) is working in lapply. From what I understand of lapply,function(x) is being applied to stats. It seems like function(x) is taking the AVGFP column from each slice1...40 and if the max number of rows in any particular column is less than the max from stats it will insert an NA. I am also unsure how the do.call function works, though I will do my best to look into it.

Comment: @user2813055 you are right about `lapply(stats, function(x)...)`. Note that `c` merely concatenates two vectors. `do.call` is an idiosyncrasy of R, because it simply creates a call like `cbind(L[[1]], L[[2]], ..., L[[40]])`. And `cbind` puts the vectors together in a matrix, columnwise.